# How hard would it be to swap a BMW B58 engine into a Supra mk3 A70?

Tags: engine, toyota, bmw, swap, supra

I am still at feasibility study stage.

The thinking behind is, since 1JZ & 2JZ swap for A70, A80, A90 Supra are all relatively matured, and A90 Supra is natively using a B58 engine, how hard would it be to put A90 stock engine (BMW b58) into A70?

Comment: As of Nov 2023, no such swap has been done, or published online yet.

Comment: "How hard" is very subjective. What's hard to you may not be to me. Do you have a garage with all of the tools and a lift? Do you have the funds to be able to do the swap? Are you ready for your swap (since nobody has ever done it before) to nickel and dime you (continue to cost you money well after the point you believe you have the parts you need) throughout the build lifecycle? Will the engine fit? Most likely. What will you need to know/do to accomplish this? Only way to know is for you to do it and tell us. I'm thinking this question is going to be off-topic because of subjectivity.